# Is Spirit Airlines's $9 Fare Club worth it?

Tags: air-travel, budget, airlines, loyalty-programs, spirit-airlines

Has anyone tried [Spirit Airlines's $9 fare club](https://www.spirit.com/StaticFareClubEnrollment.aspx) membership ($60/year)?
What do you get with your membership, and what makes it worth it?

Comment: Can you add a little bit more information about that club? Maybe a link or something like that? I have never heard of it.

Comment: Singapore's [Tiger Airways has a similar scheme called 'Stripes'](http://www.tigerairways.com/sg/en/stripes.php). Such fare clubs only give you the opportunity to be the first to take a shot a lowest fares, typically 6 months+ in the future. For most instances when you're looking for flights within the next few months, it's highly likely that those cheapest flights are already sold you and you'll be on the normal sliding scale of fares everyone else sees.

Comment: What is your question? According to the [FAQ](http://travel.stackexchange.com/faq#dontask), poll-type questions are off-topic, and that's how this one reads to me. *What kind of questions should I* not *ask here? ... there is no actual problem to be solved: “I’m curious if other people feel like I do.”*

Comment: While it's perhaps not phrased correctly, asking for whether it is possible to get low fares through a fare club is, I think, on-topic.

Comment: I paid the fee and cant seem to get any benefits, cheap tickets, just run around

Answer (score 6):

"worth the investment" is highly subjective. For some people it may be, for others not. For me e.g. it wouldn't be as I never even come close to one of their destinations, let alone flying with them :) 
As to what it offers, [the FAQ](http://spirit.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/511/related/1) is a tad vague but lists general categories:

> What are the benefits of the $9 Fare Club?
>
> The $9 Fare Club offers all of our member exclusive travel deals, not
>   only in the U.S. but all over the Americas. All the way from Lima,
>   Peru in the South to Plattsburgh, New York in the North. Not a bad
>   deal, eh? Benefits include:
>
> · Access to Member Only fares sometimes as low as $9!
>
> · Exclusive offers on hotels, rental cars and other travel
>   necessities.
>
> · Savings of $10 per bag when booking online. (Up to $120 per customer
>   in bag fees, based on roundtrip travel with a carry-on bag and 5
>   checked bags.)

So in theory you could save double the cost of the "club" just by your baggage fees, depending on how often and with how many bags you travel with them.

Answer (score 4):

After asking the question - and not receiving any answers within the hour - I kept googling around and came up with this: http://www.elliott.org/blog/is-spirit-airlines-fare-club-worth-the-money-can-i-get-my-money-back-if-it-isnt/

So I'm not sure I will be buying into the club.

Comment: Do you mind providing a short summary of the information you found? It's preferable to avoid links-only answers, as stuff tends to disappear off the internet, and your answer wouldn't be much useful if that happens.

Comment: From the linked article, it seems to indicate that the primary benefit is access to periodic sales that are sent via email to members.  Thing is, though, there are other airlines such as American that will do this for free (opt-in page on their website when you log in with your free AAdvantage account).

Answer (score 4):

It depends on a lot of things: where you go, when you want to go, how flexible you are...

The club is better as a convenience purchase than an advance plan. I think the best way to deal with Spirit's $9 club is to wait to join until there's an airfare you want, and can't get without the membership. Sometimes the money you'll save (compared to their non-club fare) will be a significant chunk of the membership fee, so that the fee will "pay for itself" if you use it just once more, and not be a significant loss if you don't.

Answer (score 1):

Sprit has a free discount option: [booking in person at the airport](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/57744/just-how-much-cheaper-is-booking-spirit-flights-at-airport-vs-online). The discount often results in a similar price and is sometimes even cheaper than the $9 fare club. No bag discount though.

No need to pay for this discount, but you will need to make an extra trip to the airport to book, so this is for those with easy access to one of their airport locations.