# Cheapest flight/travel from Boston to Los Angeles

Tags: air-travel

How can I find the cheapest flight from Boston to Los Angeles? I am flexible on dates.

Somebody told me they can get a $35 dollar flight on Sprint or other cheap air agencies, from Chicago to Los Angeles. I am trying to find the same thing.

Or, if I can do a part by train/bus and rest by flight but still cheap, that would be wonderful.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few tips beyond just doing a broad flight search.

Finding anywhere near this cheap of a connection seems to require no value for your time and a lot of flexibility but I did a search of several cities which you can find $1 bus tickets to. It'll also take a lot of searching.

There don't seem to be that cheap of direct flights from Boston, but you can look for nearby cities you can find $1 bus tickets to, like NYC, or you could look for flights to somewhere like Las Vegas and look for a $1 bus from there to LA. [Here's some info on how to find those](https://www.busbud.com/blog/busbud-launches-the-dollar-bus-club/) (full disclosure: I work for this site).

The other thing you can do is look for flights where Spirit charge their lowest fare and patch two together. [You can save about $18 off of thier fares if you go to the airport to book](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/57744/just-how-much-cheaper-is-booking-spirit-flights-at-airport-vs-online), so currently their lowest anywhere seem to be around $16 at the airport. From there it's a big jump to their $100 transcontential fares. But you can patch two or more of these cheapest flights together somewhere in the middle of the country like Chicago.

For instance I found a flight from [New York LGA to Chicago for $16](https://www.google.com/flights/#search;f=LGA;t=ORD,MDW;d=2015-11-17;r=2015-12-20;tt=o;sel=LGAORD0NK847) and the you can flight onward from [Chicago to LAX for $36](https://www.google.com/flights/#search;f=ORD,MDW;t=LAX;d=2015-11-17;r=2015-12-20;tt=o;sel=ORDLAX0NK731) (after booking at the airport discount), plus megabus is about $5 from Boston to New York and you have to stay the night at La Guardia airport. Total $57.

Comment: Thanks , but the point is that you never can get this prices