# Cheaper Sun Country flights at the airport?

Tags: bookings, airlines, fees-and-charges

Other US ULCC airlines [Spirit](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/57744/cheaper-spirit-flights-at-the-airport), Frontier, and Allegiant all charge fees for using their websites and call centers. These fees are waived when purchasing at the airport so they can claim it's an optional fee don't have to pay taxes on it - meaning customers can save money buy buying at the airport.

Does Sun Country do this too?

I can't find a breakdown of the flight price anywhere on the Sun Country website. The price is always presented as a total including taxes and fees.