# How often do Spirit $9 Fares get posted?

Tags: budget, loyalty-programs, fares, spirit-airlines

I'm a semi-frequent traveler (3-5x/year), and I'm debating whether to join the Spirit $9 Fare Club.

My question is, how frequently do these club fares pop up? How does Spirit schedule these things?

For example, do they pop up on Tuesdays, or on a set schedule?

Do they happen during the holidays?

I'm guessing it's a probability game, on the chance there will be a reduced fare on the route I'm taking, at the time I'm booking. But I'm wondering how often during the year and in general these club fares pop up. And if people have tips on the best time to book to grab these reduced fares.

Comment: related: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/5646/is-spirit-airliness-9-fare-club-worth-it?rq=1

Comment: *[...] there are sales nearly every week that are only available to $9 Fare Club members. The person notes that the club has a “ton” of members, but if you don’t check email regularly, you’ll miss out and consider the club useless. Also, the prime fares (LGA-FLL, ORD–FLL, etc.) sell out fast, so members have to be quick.* from http://www.elliott.org/blog/is-spirit-airlines-fare-club-worth-the-money-can-i-get-my-money-back-if-it-isnt/ (scroll down to **Update**)